# Получить ответ от сервера

Tags: javascript

```
FormData.prototype.appendAll = function(obj) {
    for (let key in obj)
        this.append(key, obj[key]);
    return this;
};


fetch('/ajax/', {body: new FormData().appendAll({data:1}), method: 'POST'}).
    then(s => {
        console.log(s);
        eval(s);
    }).catch(er => {
         console.log(er);
    });
```

Вопрос в том, как избавиться от FormData. То есть чтобы php получил тот же запрос с параметрами, как если бы мы отправляли путем GET.

В примере, в php получаем $_POST['data']. Как данные в php доставать тем же путем, единственно не использовать FormData, не использовать url строчку в качестве передаче параметров.

Comment: "Получить ответ от сервера" ........ "чтобы php получил тот же запрос"  --- не можете определиться кто откуда всё же что должен получить? .............  "как избавиться от FormData"  --- так всё же как получить ответ, получить запрос или избавиться от формдата? может быть всё же чётко сформулируете что нужно?

Comment: Хотелось бы чтобы было проще с параметрами, без FormData, без append.

Comment: $.ajax({url: '/ajax/', type: 'POST', data: {md:1}***

Comment: Так при помощи библиотеки, просто, хотелось бы на чистом js...

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вы имели ввиду такой способ:

```
let data = new URLSearchParams();
data.append(`key1`, `value1`);
data.append(`key2`, `value2`);


fetch('/ajax/', {body: data, method: 'POST'})
    .then(s => {
        console.log(s);
        eval(s);
    }).catch(er => {
         console.log(er);
    });
```